# How to get settings and file explorer back in Ubuntu 23.04

Tags: upgrade, 23.04

I just upgraded to 23.04 desktop and am very surprised to find that I no longer have a file explorer or settings app. Neither appear in the applications list. When I press the hotkey that I have to open the file explorer it opens vscode instead. And if I right-click on the desktop and choose Settings nothing at all happens. Apt insists that I'm fully up to date.

Also it seems I've lost the media player and VLC at least, maybe others. I can reinstall VLC but I'm not sure what the default media player is called.

How can I get these these applications back and possibly find out what else was lost?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how to find what else might have been affected but here's what worked to get back the minimum.

File explorer: I installed `nautilus`.
Settings: I installed `gnome-control-center`
Audio: I had to `modprobe snd-hda-intel` and install `pulseaudio`